# Grab a portion of List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List, looking like this:

```
some headline content
a subheadline containing the keyword 
1 2015-05-05 some data
2 2015-05-05 some data
3 2015-05-05 some data
some content
a subheadline containing another keyword 
useless stuff
```

So now I want to grab all the stuff between "keyword" and "another keyword".
Maybe I should find the index of "keyword" and "another keyword" and use **.GetRange()**, but is there a more elegant way to do this with e.g. **LINQ**?

Comment: Do you also want to search for the keywords in the Linq expression?

Comment: It appears that you should take step back and use Regexp on raw data, what you are trying to do seems like bad idea.

Comment: Mark: No, I don't need the keywords, but the stuff between the keywords.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile`

```
var newList = list.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("keyword"))
                  .Skip(1)
                  .TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("another keyword"))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

`yourList.Skip(10).Take(5);`

This will skip 10 items, then return the next 5.

But this will only work if you already know the indexes of the keywords.

Answer (score -5):

```
List<String> stringsColl=new List<String>();
strinsColl.Add(..some you strs);
...
foreach(var str in stringsColl)
{
  if(str.Contains("keyword")
   {
      ...do some work
   }
}
```